# How to run a sequence of futures without blocking and wait until completion?

Tags: scala, future

I have a requirement in Scala to run a series of http calls that have to be completed in sequence and without blocking. How can I achieve that?

Comment: look at `Future.sequence` function https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html

Comment: `Future.sequence` does not keep the order of the `in` `Iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at the `foldLeft` function or your `TraversableLike` containing the series of calls or their specs:

```
val seriesOfOrderedCalls = Seq(..)
val eventuallyCompleted = seriesOfOrderedCalls
  .foldLeft(Future.successful(()))((prev, call) => {
    prev.flatMap { _ =>
      // do your call here
      // then return the future of the call
      Future.successful(())
    }
  })
```